# How to load an excel file from an item in an array, from a table view in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, excel

I am a healthcare financial analyst and I have NO kowledge of xcode...but I just built my first application in Xcode for iPhone. My table view show three items below. I would like each item in the below array to load a different excel file.

1. Census
2. ER Shifts
3. Contacts

The first item in the array in Census.  My question is, how do I go about loading an excel file which relates to Census, ER Shifts, and so on.  I have separate 3 excel files which relates to each item in the array in my Supporting Files Folder in xode.

Please forgive me if this question is too basic.  I just started to learn XCode last week and am on a new adventure.

Thanks.
Meena

Comment: I don't think Xcode can load Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

as H2CO3 said, you can't load an excel file in Xcode (is that what you mean?) but if it's in say, a CSV file, you can use something like (https://github.com/davedelong/CHCSVParser) and parse the CSV file and load it into a some view (UITableview, UICollectionView, etc.) and stuff like that. If you're looking to recreate excel full-blown, and keep going back and forth between the views and the CSV is possible but that sounds like a lot of work